# Disclose reason for departure if company shutdown?

Tags: resume

I've worked at 2 previous companies where the company has shutdown. I was at one of these companies for 3 years, another for 2 years. I'm wondering if I should note this on my resume so to signal to people that I didn't change jobs because of performance reasons. Is it necessary? Obviously during any type of conversation, they will probably ask me, and I will mention it. What's the norm here?

I do have a great relationship with the people I've worked for. I'm still in touch with these people and a reference is definitely not a problem. I just thought it is a turn off for people looking at my resume, because I have many companies on it. I guess trying to explain some of it is probably not the right strategy?

Answer (score 6):

Given that your time at each company is not very short (two or three years is more than reasonable), then just put the dates.  It may only come up if they are looking for references from people at those previous organisations, at which point you can tell them that they've wound up.

Hopefully you have some contacts from there to verify your employment if so asked, otherwise it's not really an issue worth raising.

Comment: If they are worried about you being a "sort termer" they will ask you in the interview.  That is the appropriate time to tell them about the circumstances.  I've been a mostly-contractor-sometimes-employee for decades and they always ask me the same thing (if I'm being hired for a salaried position).

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not necessary to include the reasons on your resume.

> What's the norm here?

Generally, people don't put the reasons in the resume. The reasons and other details can always be discussed in the interview.

As you say you already have a good relationship with your ex-colleagues, you might want to give them a heads-up about a probable call from your current employer, regarding a background check.

> I just thought it is a turn off for people looking at my resume,
>   because I have many companies on it

Yes, companies do freak out when they look at the number of companies, assuming that you are a quick jumper. So, they would definitely ask you for the reason behind that, to which you already have valid reasons.

So, **it is not necessary to include the reasons on your resume.**